# Canvas Fingerprinting on Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, canvas

I have been experimenting with [Canvas Fingerprinting](https://www.browserleaks.com/canvas#how-does-it-work) to provide another layer of user identification for my database... It's a layer that I know an experienced hacker can get around since the fingerprint is created client side, but, hey, the more security layers the better, right?

Unfortunately, each Windows 7 computer I test the fingerprint on for Google Chrome produces the same fingerprint.  For example, go to this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/af1pL6fb/5/ All of the Win7/Chrome machines I've used result in a hash of 503251348.  If so many different users get the same hash, the fingerprint is useless.

I've tried to draw all sorts of random things on the canvas to get each computer to produce a slightly different result - as is the theory - but with everything I try each Chrome browser keeps giving the same results.

Anyone know of why Chrome is behaving like this when other same browsers of other computers are giving me different results (as expected)?

Or anyone know of something I can include in the canvas to encourage differing results?

OR anyone know of a different metric I can use to diferentiate between computers?  For example, I'm looking at the navigator.mimeType array as a potential way of having a semi-unique indicator for a specific browser.

Here's my fingerprint function:

```
function fingerprint() {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var txt = 'i9asdm..$#po((^@KbXrww!~cz';
    ctx.textBaseline = "top";
    ctx.font = "16px 'Arial'";
    ctx.textBaseline = "alphabetic";
    ctx.rotate(.05);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#f60";
    ctx.fillRect(125,1,62,20);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#069";
    ctx.fillText(txt, 2, 15);
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(102, 200, 0, 0.7)";
    ctx.fillText(txt, 4, 17);
    ctx.shadowBlur=10;
    ctx.shadowColor="blue";
    ctx.fillRect(-20,10,234,5);
    var strng=canvas.toDataURL();

    var hash=0;
    if (strng.length==0) return;
    for (i = 0; i < strng.length; i++) {
        char = strng.charCodeAt(i);
        hash = ((hash<<5)-hash)+char;
        hash = hash & hash;
    }
    return hash;
}
```

Comment: If you want the fingerprint to be different, shouldn't `txt` be different each time `fingerprint()` is called, instead of hard-coded? I tested your fiddle on chrome and FF, and `hash` is always the same on both (which makes sense looking at your codes, as I don't expect `strng` to be different).

Comment: No, the way canvas fingerprinting is supposed to work is you draw the exact same image for all users, but every browser/computer draws the image in a slightly different way.  So if you turn that image into data, you end up getting a string that is unique per browser - even though each browser was told to draw the exact same thing.

Comment: That is wierd. I got the same hash going to your link. I started messing with this yesterday and first thing I did was get [fingerprint.js](https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs) because I knew my attempts would be noobish at best. You [can visit my site](https://piotrkula.com/Stats) and it will generate a different fingerprint for each browser on the same computer. Not sure why Chrome would always generate the same fingerprint since Google uses this to track us now.

Comment: I also read somewhere that you could use the CRC bit after encoding the canvas to BASE64 using PNG instead of JPG. Maybe that's why you getting the same result each time because its using some cheap JPEG compression.

Answer (score 9):

There is a library called [fingerprint.js](https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs) that seems to work pretty well.

- It will get a fingerprint for non HTML 5 clients
- Enabling canvas will increase accuracy when available
- If enabled, it can create a more unique fingerprint based on the plugins installed on the browser (Although not sure why you would need that)

I have embedded this script on my site and [you can get fingerprinted here](https://piotrkula.com/Stats) to test. It works in incognito mode on the same browser and Chrome gets fingerprinted differently on other computers.

I am going to try and work on the business logic to try and link fingerprints to the same people. Obviously it is difficult on a dead site like mine where requests are few but its worth a stab.

---

You could try and use the 32bit CRC on PNG as [described on this site](https://www.browserleaks.com/canvas#how-does-it-work). `atob` not supported in IE <= 9.

```
var b64 = canvas.toDataURL.replace("data:image/png;base64,","");
var bin = atob(b64);

// crc32 takes only 4 bytes and placed from 16 to 12 byte from the end of file
var crc = bin2hex(bin.slice(-16,-12));
```

My Signature was **FE72FC19** bases on that method.

Comment: My original code was based off of finterprint.js.  I stripped out all of the code that makes a fingerprint based on other things like screen resolution and user agent.  Things like that I could easily see changing over time as new monitors are plugged in or browsers update.  I will try the PNG actions you described.  I could see how that could make for a more unique identifier if it's then relying on the computer's graphics chip to form the PNG.

Comment: Well I noitced today I went to my site and I have a new identifier... I did install a plugin (but did not enable it in plugin) but nothing else changed :( Ponders